# How do I delete the lines in a range that contain a given string from a script?

Tags: bash, sed, parameter, pattern-matching

I believe the title is self-explanatory. 
I have some files given as parameters and the given string is the last parameter of my script.
I have tried the two scripts below and do not know how I could make both of them work.
I feel I'm missing some '\' characters in both scripts, where I am specifying the pattern(string) to be found, within the sed command.

```
#!/bin/bash
a=${@: -1} # get last parameter into a variable
or ((i=1; i<$#; i++)) # for each parameter, except the last one
    do
        sed -i '1,30{/$a/d}' "${!i}" # delete each line in the i-th file, in range 1-30
                                      # containing $a (last given parameter)
    done
```

second attempt:

```
#!/bin/bash
a=${@: -1} # get last parameter into a variable
for file in "${@:1:$# - 1}"
do
    sed -i '1,30{/$a/d}' $file
done
```

Comment: Welcome! Could you post a sample of the file, what are the string parameters, and the expected aoutput?

Comment: @guillermochamorro hi! Sure, will do; I will post my answer the edit my qestion adding what you required. I’ve managed to solve my problem and now everything works as expected. The problem in my case was the fact that I was using single-quoted marks instead of double ones, thus variable expansion wouldn t work. But thank you!

Comment: By including the `$a` inside single quotes, the shell isn't expanding that variable -- you're passing a literal `$a` to `sed`.

Comment: @AndyDalton yes, indeed. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was not using double-quoted marks, but single-quoted ones, instead; therefore [variable expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) was not possible.

Here are both working scripts, along with the input&output files @guillermo chamorro asked for and an example of calling ( not sure if I m using the word 'calling' correctly here; let's say 'using') the script from the terminal:

**file1** ( **file2** has the same content )

```
Out of the first 30 lines of this file I will be deleting only those that contain 
the character substring given as a parameter.
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12    
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
30
31
32
33
...
and so on
```

**function_shell_1**

```
#!/bin/bash
a=${@: -1} # store last argument in a variable

    #part of the for-loop line is commented because of the first hashtag character

for ((i=1; i<$#; i++)) # consider all arguments, but the last one
do
    sed -i "1,30{/$a/d}" "${!i}" 
    # for each i-th line among the first 30 lines, do in-place deletions 
    #(-i dictates the in-place part) of each one containing the value of the
    # a variable
done
```

**function_shell_2** ( only minor changes regarding the for-loop)

```
#!/bin/bash
a=${@: -1} # store last argument in a variable

for fisier in "${@:1:$# - 1}" # consider all arguments, but the last one
do
    sed -i "1,30{/$a/d}" $fisier         
    # for each i-th line among the first 30 lines, do in-place deletions 
    #(-i dictates the in-place part) of each one containing the value of the
    # a variable
done
```

**script command example:**

```
./function_shell_1 file1 file2 '2'
#./function_shell_2 file1 file2 '2'
```

Both of these two above work exactly the same, producing the same expected changes in both **file1** and **file2**, i.e.:

```
Out of the first 30 lines of this file I will be deleting only those that contain
the character substring given as a parameter.
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
31
32
33
...
and so on
```